# Fixed-point bounds for optimisation using scipy linprog

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, linear-programming

I want to run an optimisation problem repeatedly to further refine the end result.

Essentially, the objective is to minimise the maximum of a set of variables (subject to inequality and equality constraints), *and then* minimise the maximum of the set **excluding** the maximum, *and then* minimise the maximum of the set **excluding** the two largest numbers and so on...

The algorithm I have in mind is:

1. Run `scipy.linprog(..., bounds=[(-numpy.inf, numpy.inf), (-numpy.inf, numpy.inf), (-numpy.inf, numpy.inf), ...])` with all variables unbounded, to minimise the maximum of the set of numbers.
2. Assuming optimisation problem is feasible and successfully solved, fix the maximum to `opt_val` by setting `bounds=[..., (opt_val, opt_val), ...]`, where all other variables have the bounds `(-numpy.inf, numpy.inf)`.
3. Make inequality constraints corresponding to that variable ineffective, by changing the coefficient of `b_ub` to `numpy.inf`.
4. Rerun simulation with modified bounds and inequality vector.

This can run without error, but it seems like scipy/numpy explicitly ignore the bounds I place on the variables - I get results for the variables that I have 'fixed' that are not the corresponding `opt_val`.

Can scipy handle bounds that restrict a variable to a single floating point number? 
Is this the best way to be solving my problem?

The code I have developed is really quite extensive, which is why I have not posted it here, so of course I don't expect a code-based solution. What I am looking for here is a yes/no answer as to whether scipy can handle bounding intervals restricted to a single float, and, on a higher level, whether I have the correct approach.

The documentation at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html does not explicitly say whether or not it is possible to specify fixed-point bounds.

Comment: Try a better LP solver. Scipy.optimize.linprog is not very robust.

Comment: For those looking for a source to verfiy @ErwinKalvelagen's comment:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43106053/why-does-scipy-optimize-linprog-return-a-solution-that-does-not-satisfy-constrai/43106433

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was a problem with relaxing the inequality constraints. I had mistakenly relaxed *all* constraints regarding the fixed variables, when instead I needed to have relaxed *some* of the constraints.

@ErwinKalvelagen's comment is still worth noting however.